# Algorithm: optimize production schedule with GA

Tags: algorithm, optimization, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I'm kind of stuck in a problem that overpasses my IQ capacities and therefore I write here to ask for some advice. Basically it seems a quite simple case.

I have a range of products:

[image: Orders Table]

I have 4 parallel machines that can make each product (no dependencies between the products):

M1
M2
M3
M4

Each of the machines can operate 24/7 **but** they need the presence of staff in order to launch each new product production.

A simple issue is for example to avoid to launch a production that will stop at night (while there is no employee to relaunch production) or on weekends.

If product C as a production duration of 2 days, I should not start production on a Thursday afternoon because the production would end on Saturday morning and the machine wouldn’t start new production before staff returns on Monday morning.

I started by trying a brute force approach (not very subtle) trying all combinations possible but I quite quickly found out that processing times were exploding :)

I then decided to do a linear programming solving, placing the most urgent job at first and picking the best machine each time and preceding this way for each product.

I got some results but obviously not the best. Therefore I look for good advice for my research. I tried to look at "ant colony" optimization or "genetic algorithms" but I faced the problem that I had variable idle times depending on the ending times of my tasks.

Comment: Genetic algorithms or Evolution strategy should work rather will for this. A partial solution would be a vector of start-times for each product (that must not be on a weekend or at night) and mutations would be shifting start times some minutes or hours back and forth.

Comment: Just wondering: Do you actually have to do an assignment of tasks to machines, or is it enough the check whether there's no time with more than four tasks in parallel?

Comment: Thanks Tobias for your answer. My goal is to produce a Gantt diagram (therefore an the best assignement of products / time / machine). Was it your question?

Comment: My question was: Is there any case, where there are never more than four tasks in parallel, and yet the tasks can not be distributed to four machines (without interrupting and relocating a task)? I'd say "no", which would simplify the optimization problem quite a bit (you can then assign tasks to machines afterwards), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, simultaneously all 4 machines should be staffed -- > 4 parallel tasks. Once tasks launched they shouldn't be interrupted (there are setup times before each task).

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I'll try to have a better understanding on how genetic algorithms work and how I could fit them to my problem. Looks like I have still a lot of job ahead ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @tobias_k, I've been exploring Genetic Algorithms for my scheduling problem.

I think they are very promising and started to write what would be my chromosome sequencing :
Given products (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,M) and machines (M1,M2,M3,M4) a possible coding could be would be ['EKM', 'IFB', 'GLD', 'HAJC'] (EKM on machine 1 in this order, IFB on machine 2 etc..)

I have no difficulty measuring the fitness (my goal is to minimise makespan) but when it comes to crossover, this is something much more complicated (looks that it is the hard part of genetic algorithms).

If I have two parents :  ['EKM', 'IFB', 'GLD', 'HAJC'] and ['ICFM', 'HLK', 'DJE', 'BGA'] I'm actually looking at the machine on which the product is made (for A for example it is M3 on both) and randomly select which one to choose. I do the same with to choose the order in which it is made (for A it would be position 2 on parent 1 and position 3 on parent 2) and randomly choose.

I'm pretty much convinced I'm making an error here but can't find a way to find a good chromosome coding / crossover strategy (and my bad results show so).

Would anyone having a larger GA knowledge than I do could help with an advice?

Many thanks!